# PHP image encoding not working

Tags: php, android, post, encoding, jpeg

I'm trying to encode a .jpg file on my server and send the string back to my android app. The PHP encoding function doesn't seem to be working - I always get a null response.

```
...

} else if ($tag == 'getPhoto') {
    $filePath = $_POST['filePath'];
    $filePath = mysql_real_escape_string($filePath);
    $photo_str = $db->getPhotoString($filePath);
    $photo_str = mysql_real_escape_string($photo_str);
    if (!empty($photo_str)) {
        echo $photo_str;
    } else {
        echo 'Something went wrong while retrieving the photo.';
    }
}

...

public function getPhotoString($filePath) {
    $type = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $photoData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $photo_str = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($photoData);
    // $photo_str = 'test_response';
    return $photo_str;
}
```

I know my filepath is correct because when I change it I get an error that says the file/directory doesn't exist. And, the "test_response" works when I uncomment it. Please help!

**UPDATE - relevant android code:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));       
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
photoString = convertResponseToString(response);
Log.d("string response", photoString);

public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{          
    String res = "";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..                   
    if (contentLength < 0) {
    } else {
           byte[] data = new byte[512];
           int len = 0;
           try {
               while (-1 != (len = is.read(data))) {
                   buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           try {
               is.close(); // closing the stream…..
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..
    }
    //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `I always get a null response.`. From who? Where?

Comment: When I echo $photo_str, it comes up as null when I toast it in my app.

Comment: Have you echoed `$filePath`? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. As I said, when I changed filePath in the httppost, it gives an error saying the file/directory doesn't exist. But it doesn't give the error as it is now.

Comment: Please tell what actually is its value. I assume that it is a relative path? You did tell nothing about $db. What is it?

Comment: I showed the file path in the comments in the answer below. $db is a reference to a script with functions in it. It is irrelevant though because the everything executes as it should when I uncomment the "test_response".

Comment: Ok. You already did that. Have you checked the filesize of the .jpg? I suggest you place a .txt file in the uploads dir. So you can try to retrieve that without having to encode. Add more echo statements to check values on null. Are you sure you read the stream correctly? It is so strange that you receive a null as certainly no null will be send.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that. So i can use file_get_contents ('uploads/test.txt') then just echo??

Comment: Yes indeed try that.

Comment: it works. I get the text of the test.txt file

Comment: Now then take again a known .jpg and try step by step. One step at a time. Echo  file size for instance first.  Step by step. Echo all details. Please show also your Android code.

Comment: hmm this might provide some insight! i used getimagesize, used json_encode to echo the array: {"0":768,"1":1280,"2":3,"3":"width=\"768\" height=\"1280\"","bits":8,"mime":"image\/png"} ... why does it say png when it's a jpg file?

Comment: Don't know. By why would it matter? Android code?

Comment: I think there was something wrong with my convertResponseToString method because I'm getting an encoded string when i use photoString = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

Comment: post an answer saying use photoString = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString(); and I will up-vote and choose answer. Thanks for your time. I'm sorry for wasting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, only a suggestion but i'm not able to comment as i don't have enough reputation xD. Anyway, did you try to echo `$photoData` after

```
$photoData = file_get_contents($filePath);
```

to see if it's filled with something? Maybe you get a null result. Also, can you tell me what's $filePath value when taken from $_POST variable and when passed to `getPhotoString($filePath)` function? I'm thinking about something wrong with mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and added:
if ($photoData === FALSE) {
   return 'Error';
  } ... it still returned a null string. I also removed both mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: do you have the right permission on the folder where the jpg image is located on server?

Comment: I'm a noob so I don't know how to change that. Can you tell me?? :)

Comment: Sure, i suppose you have access to the apache server that hosts php pages and your image. From a command line (let's suppose the folder that holds the image is "/var/www/image/image.jpg") write:
`cd /var/www/`
then `ls -l`

and post the result here. So we can see who is the owner of the folder and what permission you have

Comment: By the way, what is your configuration? Do you use LAMP environment? (Linux Apache Mysql PHP)? or windows based server? (like easyphp)

Comment: Ya I'm using XAMPP on windows so I don't have the command line you speak of.

Comment: Ok, then can you tell me the path that you receive in your $_POST variable?

Comment: uploads/w/547129a0ae3584.52916892.jpg < the exact location of the jpeg relative to the path used in the httppost

Comment: I really don't know how to help you right now as i'm not used to windows environment, but try to put a slash (/) before uploads

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the error saying the file/directory doesn't exist. It's okay though, I appreciate the time you spent helping me.

Comment: You are welcome, i'm sorry that i cannot help you more. if i find something usefull related to your question i will let you know. Good luck in the meanwhile